# Detect the thread that created an object

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to, for the development of a [new Blocking Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) be able to know the thread origin of an object being used in the queue.

One could, of course, do this:

```
/**
 * An immutable, threadsafe object that is uniquely identified by the
 * thread that created it. All extending objects must call super in the
 * constructor and assert during equality that the super classes are also
 * considered equal.
 *
 * If subclasses choose to extend this object and make their representation
 * mutable, please note that the object will still be considered to originate
 * from the thread it was constructed on.
 */
public class ThreadUniqueObject {

    private final long threadId;

    public long getThreadId() {
        return threadId;
    }

    public ThreadUniqueObject() {
        this.threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof ThreadUniqueObject)) return false;
        return ((ThreadUniqueObject)obj).getThreadId() == this.getThreadId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int)threadId;
    }

}
```

and then require that only subclasses of this class could be used in the queue. However, is there any solution using some magic I am not aware of, that could detect the thread that created an object? I can't even find a private field that I could grab through reflection that indicates this. Any ideas?

Comment: "I can't even find a private field that I could grab through reflection that indicates this." No, that doesn't surprise me at all. Bear in mind that it would be incredibly rare for this to be useful information - I wouldn't expect to pay a memory penalty for *every single Java object ever created* for such a niche use case. I think you'll need to write the code yourself, and limit your collection to appropriate types.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to confirm this. The queue, in development itself, and why it uses this information, is here https://github.com/DylanModesitt/AcceptorBlockingQueue.

Comment: Could you pass the thread ID in as a parameter to your put methods? Alternatively, are the objects submitted to the queue by the same thread that produced them? In that case, the put method could store the thread that submitted the objects.

Comment: Quickly looking over that code and its doc, the queue is the right place to put this code. There should be a multiplexer feeding the queue that keeps track of the threads and their being blocks.

Comment: I thought about this, and its perfectly valid, I just did not want to put a restriction on where one puts the items, in case you wanted to generate a ton of them say on an unbounded, synchronized, other queue or list from different threads and then put them on this at a later date. Say one has a network of these queues, etc that made this impossible. But one could definitely do it this way, I was just afraid of the generalization. It definitly beats requiring an object to inherit this though if no other solution is there.

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily have to inherit. `ThreadUniqueObject` could also be a container, merely wrapping the actual value. But that would still require the container to be created in the same thread as the value (which could be "enforced" by making the value class' constructor private and instead offering a factory method that returns a `ThreadUniqueObject` with a new instance).

Comment: @MalteHartwig absolutely another thought.

Comment: But *why*? There are already monitoring and profiling tools providing this information for the tasks where I can imagine it to be useful. But why should a blocking queue implementation need to know this? By the way, “All extending objects must call super in the constructor” is an obsolete statement. There is no way how subclasses could skip calling `super()`, it will be called even if you don’t write `super();` explicitly.

Comment: @Holger why the information is useful is in the doc of the queue mentioned in the comments. And yes I also see that

Comment: That idea is illogical. The thread which created the object is not necessarily the thread putting the object into the queue. If these threads differ, it is impossible for your queue to block the creator thread, all it could do, is to block the thread putting the object, but blocking thread X because the object’s creator was thread Y makes no sense. At least, this doesn’t explain even remotely why someone may want this.

Comment: @Holger There is some purpose to it. The assumption is that the production threads are instantiating the blocking queue messages, but the thread that places these created objects onto the designed queue could live on a different thread, as they could be held in a synchronized collection.

Comment: But the production threads *do not stop*, as you are only blocking the putting thread. On the other hand, when the putting thread has been blocked, it has been blocked because of one specific creator (production thread), but can’t put items from other production threads then. The declared intention (“block specific producer threads”) is not matching what will actually happen (“block an unspecific putting thread”). It’s also unclear what you think to gain from separating production threads and putting threads, as it only complicates your code and creates this unsolvable problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly there is no attribute holding thread id which created .Explicitly it extends Object which do not have such method.You need to implement by your own.Then in queue you have to specify.

Or you can create a marker interface and while creating object you can store the thread id.But it will not mandate for it.

```
public interface BlockingQueue<E extends Threaded> extends Queue<E>
```

Answer (score -3):

The thread that created an object is available via `Thead.currentThread()` during the object's constructor. If you need it, save it. Hard to see *why* you would need it.